Multiple catalogues same BU Einstein SFMC
I want tu publish more than one web catalogue in a unique BU.
I'm trying to update all of them in a unique catalogue, adding an indentifying field (Eg: Website_Region) in order to choose the catalog corresponding to each website using the rule manager of Einstein SFMC.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue, or if there's a more optimal way to upload different catalogues?
Thanks.

What is the reason for multiple catalogues? Is it for localisation of your fields? Or are they running entirerly separate inventory?

These are actually separate catalogues, one for each country: Austria, Germany, Ireland... The products are essentially the same and share the same IDs, but we want to differentiate them so that, for example, when we send an email to Germany, products from other websites don’t appear. It would be easier if we had more business units available, but that's not our case :(
Thank you very much!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If this is to control the product names and which URL should be selected in Germany vs Ireland, why not use this solution here - I will assume it will do what you expect.

Also, you can use tags to exclude products not being sold in a specific market, from your recommendations

A BU can only have one catalog, and list & scenarios are built from that catalog.
Which means if you combine multiple websites with different inventory into one catalog, there is still only 1 top sellers scenario (etc...) Which may mean one country can have all 100 items on the top sellers and another country will have zero
The platform goes
Catalog >> Lists/Scenarios >> Rules >> Recommendations
and not
Catalog >> Rules >> List/Scenarios >> recommendations
Which means you don't have dynamic lists, you have static lists which can manipulated by rules. Using the above example, Germany may get blank recommendations if Austria items dominate the items on the lists

Very good point, which I totally missed out in my comments to Marc. Even though I actually DID experience it in one of my old implementations :-|
